# What guidelines should I consider for a web design portfolio?

Tags: website-design, portfolio

I need to know what are the essential things that one web designer must have on his/her portfolios or things that really make a difference...the following is what i think is a good starting point. but would like to get confirmation and further tips and examples of professional portfolio also some general idea of new trends that are in for portfolios.

- I know it should show some focus toward certain niche.
- Have best examples and not like 50 pieces.
- Blog to show off other skills, and that he/she is keeping up with
  trends.
- Site Works on tablets.
- Look very well designed, especially if you are a designer.
- Give example of workflow and results.
- Preferably has worked out with one or two clients who have gotten
  great results.
- A way to quickly engage and get response.
- An outlet to network with other designers/developers.
- List of other designers/developers that you recommend and that they
  recommend you back.

what else?

Comment: Keeping things simple is probably the best option. The things you can't do without are: contact details and work your proud of. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally keep it clean and simple. I know this won't help much, but nineliondesign is a perfect example of a good looking modern protfolio. He is like my idol in the web- and graphicdesign industry

[Nine Lion Design](http://www.nineliondesign.com/)